# How to apply parallax in a background image

Tags: html, css, parallax

I have two blocks in which I have given a background image with `background-size: cover`. Now I want it to make it parallax.

Following is my code :

`HTML`:

```
<div class="personalSessDiv">
    <div class="pi-section">
            My content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="betterGradDiv">
    <div class="pi-section">
            My content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
.personalSessDiv{
    background: url(../images/common/home-bg-2.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 392px;
}
.betterGradDiv{
    background: url(../images/common/home-bg-3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 453px;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far from your end. 
Here guys don't write code for you, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking any que.

and for your query http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/, this may help.

Comment: Try this tutorial http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/ or take a look at this fiddle http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what you mean by parallax, there are so many different variations. But try add this code to the div you wish to have the scrolling effect.

Im sure you can try customize is to suit.

```
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: background-image 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-image 1s;
  -ms-transition: background-image 1s;
  -o-transition: background-image 1s;
  transition: background-image 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: I want the jquery plugin which properly suits to my code to give a parallax scrolling effect

Comment: @SharjilKhan  you should've specified that you wanted to use a jquery plugin in your question. This code is just a quick and easy way to create a slight parallax effect

Answer (score 1):

It's what I needed when I google'd your question, and it worked for me
   The CSS background-attachment Property

```
body { 
     background-image: url('image.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
}
```